# Android progress bar and service

Tags: android, service, progress, android-progressbar, intentservice

Pretty standard task: have a service with long running task. And service has to update progress bar on main screen

There are two options:

1. Use broadcast intent to send progress and handle this in activity
2. Use handle with runnable to update ui right from Service code

Which approach looks "better" for you?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would use an EventBus such as [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) (by Square) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (by greendroid), This is much less painful.

Hope this will help.